# Qt - using windows Sleep()

Tags: sleep

I want to put a brief delay in my Qt program but it's behaving oddly.  This is my code...

```
void ScribbleArea::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Right)
    {
    myLabel->setText("You pressed RightArrow");
    Sleep(1000);
    myLabel->setText("Done waiting");
    }
}
```

What I expect to happen is to see "You pressed RightArrow" followed by a 1 second pause and then "Done waiting".  But it behaves as if the Sleep() is called prior to the first setText().

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ***But it behaves as if the Sleep() is called prior to the first setText().*** That  is how Qt works. The sleep delays the GUI from updating. Even though you changed the text the actual update happens when the GUI processes the message loop. Meaning you must exit the keyPressEvent() before the update happens. I believe can also force an update using QCoreApplication::processEvents()

Comment: ***Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.*** My advice is to use a QTimer::singleShot() instead.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I've been playing with the QTimer a bit.  I'll plug away at that a bit more.

Comment: I just added the QTimer::singlShot().  Worked great.  Thanks again!

Comment: You may want to use a lambda for this like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27480834/487892